# Convert *.dwg between versions

Tags: autocad

I am using an off site drafter for much of the drawing work that I have done.  My office uses Autocad 2012 LT, while the off site drafter produces files in the 2016 format.  In order to edit the drawings I must first convert the files from the newer autocad drawing format to an older format using DWG Trueview.  Is there any way to interact with an API to complete this task?

The only programming language I know is python.  I know comtypes can interact with the DLL's so its a matter of hooking in.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to make an attempt yourself first. If after [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) you can't solve it, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937).

Comment: Why not tell your off site drafter to save all work in an earlier version that is compatible with what you have in the office?

Answer (score 1):

You can already convert drawings in batch using the **DWG Convert** tool provided with DWG TrueView, and so in my opinion there is very little benefit to be gained in investing a significant amount of time attempting to automate this process further.

Simply follow the detailed instructions & video tutorial provided [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/using-autodesk-dwg-trueview-to-convert-dwg-file-version.html).